conditions to become equivalent statement
Let's consider the statement
$$(A) \quad f(x_0, y_0) = f(x_1, y_1) \ \text{  holds iff } x_0=x_1 \text{ and } y_0 =y_1. $$
Next, consider the statements
\begin{eqnarray}
(a) \ &&  f(x_0, y_0) \neq f(x_1, y_0) \ \text{ for } x_0 \neq x_1 \\ 
(b) \ && f(x_0, y_0) \neq f(x_0, y_1) \ \text{ for } y_0 \neq y_1 \\ 
(c) \ &&  f(x_0, y_0) \neq f(x_1, y_1) \ \text{ for } x_0 \neq x_1 \text{ and } y_0 \neq y_1 
\end{eqnarray}
Clearly, (A) implies (a), (b) and (c). However, I'm not sure if all of (a), (b) and (c) are necessary to imply (A). In other words, are all of (a), (b) and (c) the necessary and sufficient condition to obtain (A)? If one of the conditions in (a), (b) and (c) is droppoed, then do the remaining conditions imply (A)?

(a), (b) and (c) are not sufficient to imply (A). Consider as $f$ the boolean function XOR, and convince yourself that it satisfies (a), (b), and (c), but not (A).
Perhaps you meant for (c) to be "$(c') x_0 \neq x_1 \textbf{ or } y_0 \neq y_1$", in which case (c') alone is (classically) equivalent to (A). Indeed $$x_0 \neq x_1 \lor y_0 \neq y_1 \to f(x_0, y_0) \neq f(x_1, y_1)$$ is the contrapositive of $$f(x_0, y_0) = f(x_1, y_1) \to x_0 = x_1\land y_0 = y_1$$ which is the non-trivial direction in (A).
Another way to repair your argument would be to define
\begin{eqnarray}
(a') \ &&  f(x_0, y_0) \neq f(x_1, y_1) \ \text{ for } x_0 \neq x_1 \\ 
(b') \ && f(x_0, y_0) \neq f(x_1, y_1) \ \text{ for } y_0 \neq y_1
\end{eqnarray}
Note the subtle difference: we don't require that one argument remains fixed while we vary the other one.
Now (a') and (b') together are equivalent to (A) (this is essentially decomposing (c') above by $\lor$-elimination).

Many thanks. If another condition (d) $f(x_0,y_0)=f(x_1,y_1)$ holds with $x_0=x_1$ and $y_0=y_1$, then, do (a), (b), (c) and (d) imply (A)?

Do you mean (d) $x_0 = x_1 \land y_0 = y_1 \to f(x_0, y_0) = f(x_1, y_1)$? That's always true, so it doesn't make a difference.

I'm a bit confused. Clearly (A) implies (a), (b), (c) and (d). Since there are two variables $x$ and $y$, it should be sufficient to consider ony four situations (1) $x_0=x_1$ and $y_0 = y_1$, (2)  $x_0\neq x_1$ and $y_0 = y_1$, (3)  $x_0=x_1$ and $y_0 \neq  y_1$, and (4)  $x_0 \neq  x_1$ and $y_0 \neq  y_1$. I think these cases are all covered with (a), (b), (c) and (d). So, I consider that conditions (a) and (b) and (c) and (d) imply (A). I'm wondering what is the problem in my understanding...

Did you think about XOR yet? We have 0 XOR 0 = 1 XOR 1, yet (0, 0) ≠ (1, 1), so XOR is not injective. The statement of injectivity does not involve four cases, so I'm not sure what your reasoning is.

Sorry, I'm not familiar with boolean function at all...

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Definition (I am writing 0 for F and 1 for T).
